# Does distinct operator use summarize underneath?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a small query where the only aggregate operator I am using is distinct , but the error I am getting is `'summarize' operator has exceeded memory budget`. That makes me wonder if distinct is basically a special case (the one without involving aggregate function) of summarize operator. e.g. `distinct col1,col2,col3` can get converted to `summarize by col1,col2,col3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. And, unlike `summarize by...`, you *can* run `distinct *` (when necessary)